# relative sorting using hashmap

Tags: c++, data-structures, hashmap

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int T,i;
    map<int,int> h;
    cin>>T;
    while(T--)
    {
        int n,m;
        cin>>n>>m;
        int arr1[n];
        int arr2[m];
        for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            cin>>arr1[n];
        }
        for(i=0;i<m;i++)
        {
            cin>>arr2[m];
        }
        for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            h[arr1[i]]++;
        }
        map<int,int>:: iterator itr;
        for(int i=0;i<m;i++)
        {    //itr=h.find(arr2[i]);
            if(h.find(arr2[i])!=h.end())
            {
                itr=h.find(arr2[i]);
            }
            while(itr->second--)
            {
                cout<<itr->first<<" ";
            }
        }
        
       for(auto x: h)
       {
           if(x.second!=0)
           {
               while(x.second--)
               {
                   cout<<x.first<<" ";
               }
           }
       }
       
       
        cout<<endl;
    }
}
```

Given two arrays A1[] and A2[] of size N and M respectively. The task is to sort A1 in such a way that the relative order among the elements will be same as those in A2. For the elements not present in A2, append them at last in sorted order. It is also given that the number of elements in A2[] are smaller than or equal to number of elements in A1[] and A2[] has all distinct elements. Note: Expected time complexity is O(N log(N)). input A1[]=2 1 2 5 7 1 9 3 6 8 8 A2[]=2 1 8 3 output: 2 2 1 1 8 8 3 5 6 7 9

i am getting segmentation fault.i am trying to make an hashmap of frequency of elements in A1[]. after that i am trying to match the keys of hashmap with elements of A2[]. i am getting segmentation fault.what am i doing wrong.

Comment: That's not a  "hashmap", that's a regular map. you might want <unordered_map>. Also, do NOT include <bits/stdc++.h> that's an oddball platform-specific thing. Use the standard headers. For this you'll need to include iostream and map (or unordered_map, depending on which you want to use). Also, try changing arr1 and arr2 to be fixed size or create them with new[] or use a vector to store them.

Answer (score 0):

```
vector<int> relSort(vector<int> A1, vector<int> A2) {
    vector<int> res;
    for (int i=0; i<A2.size(); i++){
        for (int j=0; j<A1.size(); j++){
            if (A1[j] == A2[i]){
                res.push_back(A2[i]);
                A1.erase(A1.begin()+j);
                j--;
            }
        }
    }
    sort(A1.begin(), A1.end());
    for (int i=0; i<A1.size(); i++){
        res.push_back(A1[i]);
    }
    return res;
}
```